# error while performing set_intersection with a map containing key and a structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, stdmap

I want to find intersection between two maps. My map has structure `map<int,line>`, where `line` is a structure. The problem is when i use `set_intersection` for performing the intersection i get the following error represented in the image.

[image: image shows the errors i got]

Below is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> point;
struct line
{
    int lineid;
    point starting, ending;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef map<int, line> mymap;   
    line w,x,y,z;
    w.lineid = 1;
    w.starting = { 5, 1 };
    w.ending = { 5, 100 };
    x.lineid = 2;
    x.starting = { 20, 56 };
    x.ending = { 120, 56 };
    y.lineid = 3;
    y.starting = { 100, 150 };
    y.ending = { 100, 200 };
    z.lineid = 4;
    z.starting = { 330, 50 };
    z.ending = { 330, 150 };

    mymap bin1;
    bin1.insert({ w.lineid, w });
    bin1.insert({ x.lineid, x });
    bin1.insert({ y.lineid, y });

    mymap bin2;
    bin2.insert({ x.lineid, x });
    bin2.insert({ y.lineid, y });
    bin2.insert({ z.lineid, z });

    mymap out;
    mymap::iterator out_itr(out.begin());
    set_intersection(bin1.begin(), bin1.end(), bin2.begin(), bin2.end(),
                                                 inserter(out, out_itr)); 
    cout << "" << out.size();               

        return 0;
    }
```

Any help to solve this issue will be helpful.

Comment: `line 234`? please give us exact error message..

Comment: that image is the exact error i got. it showed error in some utility file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining for not finding an `operator<` to compare lines object (you need to compare `std::pair<int, line>`, and the comparator for it needs to compare lines).

You must provide a comparator for your lines :

**Example** :

```
  bool operator<(const line& other) const
  {
      return other.lineid < lineid; // Or whatever logic you want to compare your lines.
  }
```

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/AIPsih)

**Note :**

Alternatively, you can directly provide a comparator to `set_intersection`, e.g. here with a lambda :

```
 set_intersection(bin1.begin(), 
                  bin1.end(), 
                  bin2.begin(), 
                  bin2.end(),
                  inserter(out, out_itr),
                  [] (const std::pair<int, line>& p1, const std::pair<int, line>& p2) { return p1.first != p2.first; } );
```

Comment: well both works good :) and as another alternative i think we can use `set_intersection(bin1.begin(), bin1.end(), bin2.begin(), bin2.end(),
                                                 inserter(out, out_itr),bin1.value_comp());` which also produced the same result. But logically `bin1.key_comp()` should only be used because i want to do intersection based on key and not the value. when i use `bin1.key_comp()` i get `error C2664:cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'const int &` i could understand the error dont know to solve it.